# Trouble bringing an MDI form to the front

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

Imagine I have two MDI forms inside of a parent form.

Each form has many many controls inside, some are even custom Infragistics controls such as an UltraPanel.

Currently when both forms are open and in normal sized mode (not maximize or minimized), I can only bring one form to the front of the other by clicking on the forms title bar.

If I click inside the form itself, it's not brought to the front. Is there some way for me to capture the click *anywhere* inside the MDI form and bring that one to the front?

Comment: That's not the default behaviour of MDI children. What you're asking for is what happens with standard MDI forms. Can you try eliminating controls from these forms to try to work out what's breaking the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Add a DoubleClick event to the child form and set:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```