# Clicking on form behind another doesn't fire the focusing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, click, focus

Good day everyone
I have `two forms` on my `MDI main form`. When the application starts `one form places behind the other`.

When I click on the behind form it doesn't appear in front of another form. It only appears in front of the form if I click on the `border` or on the `title bar`.

So I wonder: is this a `normal behavior` or `not`? And if not how can I fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: Are you joking? It works OK and that's the way the children forms in a MDI container should work. How did you show your children forms?

Comment: I think you have the same problem: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762418/trouble-bringing-an-mdi-form-to-the-front